# AS3 async Bitmap creation iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I'm developing an iPad app using Adobe Air.

I have all my images loaded into `BitmapData` objects when the app starts. Then I only need to create `Bitmap` objects (which are only containers) to use the pixels that are stored into the `BitmapData`objects.

This works fine until I have to create a `Bitmap` object with a big image. The app slows down, even freezes, for as much as 1 second.

As AS3 is single threaded, I cannot delegate the `Bitmap` creation to a new thread. Also if the UI is frozen, I cannot show a decent spinner to inform the user "something is going on".

How could I solve this problem?
Is there a way to create objects in parallel without affecting the UI performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems the answer was a lot simpler, and Adobe already thought of that.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS52621785137562065a8e668112d98c8c4df-8000.html

The problem is that even if the images are loaded into `BitmapData` objects, they are stil not decoded. That is why bigger images take a while to be put into `Bitmap` objects.

The solution is as simple as using an instruction to force image decoding when the images are loaded, and not when you need them. This is done using `ImageDecodingPolicy.ON_LOAD`.

```
var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(); 
loaderContext.imageDecodingPolicy = ImageDecodingPolicy.ON_LOAD; 
var loader:Loader = new Loader(); 
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.adobe.com/myimage.png"), loaderContext);
```

Comment: Much more common (albeit improper) way of doing this is to simply call `BitmapData.getPixel(0,0)` on the BitmapData you wish to load into memory. That will decode the data to get the pixel (and will work on embedded images as well). Be aware that decoding an image loads the _uncompressed_ image into memory. Due to the low amounts of RAM you can use in iOS and how large the runtime is, this can become an issue very fast.

Comment: Thanks @JoshJanusch I will keep an eye on memory. So far the solution above is working wonderfully.

Comment: I highly suggest getting Adobe Scout. It will help you immensely while trying to monitor everything performance, especially memory

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `worker`, its basicaly a background thread for as3, read up on it here [ASDocs Worker](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html)

Comment: I still don't know if that is the right answer, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: Well this is your only chance of having your own thread. You could also have a look at the Task Framework http://www.spicefactory.org/spicelib/docs/as3/current/manual/task.php

Comment: Here's more info on how to use threads with the new Flascc https://github.com/adobe-flash/crossbridge/wiki/Multithreaded-C---programming-with-the-Adobe-Flash-C---Compiler-(FlasCC)

Comment: Workers are not supported on mobile platforms, so this doesn't really help the asker.